# Can't get right information from userdata for login

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter, session, authentication, model

I'm trying to make my first login without just downloading a file and implementing it in my site.

So I made a member model (model_member) and a controller (account). In the view file im checking if the user is logged in and if they've made a character or not and to display different things based on the results of that.

But its saying I am logged in even though im not. Or my session is messing up and when i close the browser its staying logged in. (haha)

Here is my code:

Model:

```
 class model_member extends CI_Model {
    public function save ($data) {
        $this->db->insert('member', $data);

        $this->session->set_userdata('email', $data['email']);
        $this->session->set_userdata('password', $data['password']);
    }

    public function isLoggedIn () {
        if ($this->session->userdata('email')) {
            return true;
        } else if ($this->session->userdata('email')) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
 public function register () {
        //Load model
        $this->load->model('model_member');

        //If post send pass and email to model
        if ($this->input->post()) {
            $data['email'] = $this->input->post('email');
            $data['password'] = md5($this->input->post('password'));
            $this->model_member->save($data);
        }

        //Set title
        $data['title'] = 'Register';

        //Load view
        $this->template->write_view('content', 'account/register', $data);
        $this->template->render();
    }
```

And just for the sake of it, my view: (using a codeigniter template)

```
 <div id ="game-home">
<div id="intro">
    <? if ($loggedIn == true && $charMade == false) { ?>
        <a href="#">Make a Character</a>
    <? } else if ($loggedIn == False && $charMade == false) { ?>
        <a href="#">Make an Account</a>
    <? } else if ($loggedIn == true && $charMade == true) { ?>
        Game Coming Soon!
    <? } ?>
</div>
```

It's saying make a character not matter what. I've looked over it for a while and im hoping it isnt just something stupid. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Have you tried this in another browser? Just to make sure, that is not a session problem. Btw, for testing purpose you should use this:
$this->session->sess_destroy();
somewhere. If the CodeIgniter's own session uses cookie to store session data, it can cause your problem even after a browser restart.

Comment: Well well well, I sware i closed chrome and re-opened it to try it and it didnt work. But i tried it just not in IE (bleh) and it worked. Ill keep trying stuff. Maybe its cookies or something. But yeah, it was something stupid. Thanks

Comment: Where can i put the sess_destroy()?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer ----------

"Have you tried this in another browser? Just to make sure, that is not a session problem. Btw, for testing purpose you should use this: $this->session->sess_destroy(); somewhere. If the CodeIgniter's own session uses cookie to store session data, it can cause your problem even after a browser restart." – Gergely Bacso